# How within Apache Ant can I filter OUT only lines that don't begin with INSERT like I believe is possible (see below) with grep

Tags: ant

How within Apache Ant can I filter OUT only lines that don't begin with INSERT like I believe is possible (see below) with grep.

```
cat specialtable.inserts.sql | grep INSERT > specialtable.inserts.ONLY.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**linecontains**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#linecontains) or [**linecontainsregexp**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#linecontainsregexp) filter readers

```
<copy file="specialtable.inserts.sql" tofile="specialtable.inserts.ONLY.sql">
  <filterchain>
    <linecontains>
      <contains value="INSERT"/>
    </linecontains>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

If you wanted to filter the file to include all lines that contain **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, or **DELETE** then use `linecontainsregexp`:

```
<copy file="specialtable.inserts.sql" tofile="specialtable.inserts.ONLY.sql">
  <filterchain>
    <linecontainsregexp>
       <regexp pattern="INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE"/>
    </linecontainsregexp>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

You could also use the `casesensitive` attribute and a more complex REGEX expression to ensure that the lines start with those words.

Comment: Thanks that appears to work.  Now if I wanted to also include any lines that contain UPDATE OR DELETE how would I do that?

Comment: Also instead of sending the output to another file could I just update the original file?

Comment: I don't believe that you can simply update the file. You could copy to a new location and then use `move` the newly filtered file to the original file.